# How to pause and resume countdown timer?

Tags: java, android

I have a countdown timer in my game activity and I need it paused when I get incoming call or something that lose the focus from my activity. I tried like this but it does not work (the onPause method works, it stops the timer, but it wont resume it):

```
private long total = 180000;

MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(total, 1000);

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {


        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            total = millisUntilFinished;
            vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }
        }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(total, 1000);
        brojacVremena.start();
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    brojacVremena.cancel();
}
```

I tried even this in my onPause:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        MyCount brojacVremenaNew = new MyCount(total, 1000);
        brojacVremenaNew.cancel();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have any method to pause it so you will probably need to store the millis left then instantiate a new timer in `onResume()` using that stored value

Comment: see this: http://example.javamonday.com/Open-Source/Android/Timer/multitimer-android/com/cycleindex/multitimer/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.htm

Comment: Check this [How to implement pause and resume countdowntimer](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/665737/How-to-implement-pause-and-resume-countdowntimer)

Comment: @codeMagic well, I stored milis with total = millisUntilFinished;

Comment: No, total left when you pause. So that would need to go in `onPause()` and saved in shared prefs or some other persistent storage

Comment: @codeMagic Have a look at my answer. That should work, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you need to extend it, unless really necessary. I second what codeMagic said - store time time left in a variable in `onPause()` and **DO NOT** forget to save it in `onSaveInstanceState()` or to `SharedPreference`.

When your activity resumes, either due to config change or whatever, you can recreate your timer:

```
new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, tickTime) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         millisUntilFinished -= tickTime;
         // do you wanna know for whom the bell tolls?
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         // it tolls for thee
         millisUntilFinished = 0;
     }
  }.start();
```

In  `onPause()`, cancel this timer and in `onResume()` create a new instance of the timer based on how much time is left :)

**EDIT:**
Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    millisUntilFinished = getMillisFromSharedPreference(KEY);
    if(millisUntilFinished != 0){
        new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, tickTime) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             millisUntilFinished -= tickTime;
             // do you wanna know for whom the bell tolls?
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             // it tolls for thee
             millisUntilFinished = 0;
         }
        }.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    saveMillisToSharedPreference(KEY,millisUntilFinished);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `millisUntilFinished -= tickTime;` is correct. The way that is in the OP should be fine. The member variable representing time until finish needs to be stored when `onPause()` is called then instantiated with that time

Comment: First of all, that variable is a method param and you don't do anything with it after so I don't see what it's actually doing. The `millisUntilFinished` already gives you the time left in the counter. So, that value needs to be stored in a member variable as OP is doing with `total`. So, `total` just needs to be saved in `onPause()` then in `onResume()` be used `MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(totalFromSavedValue, 1000);`.

Comment: @codeMagic I am suggesting that the OP shouldn't extend the class. `millisUntilFinished` will initially be the full-length of time for which the timer should run. It is decremented by `tickTime`. In `onPause()` just save the `millisUntilFinished` value and in `onResume()`, get this value and recreate the timer. :)

Comment: If he doesn't extend it then he has to right his own count down class